# Refresh date and time in variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am loading a date and time in to a clock from a MySQL database the following way:

```
$TimeStart = strtotime( $row['TimeStart'] );
$TimeStart = date( 'Y,m,d,g,i,s', $TimeStart );

var startDateTime = new Date(<?= $TimeStart ?>);
```

An example of what I have currently is [in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe0d6j21/)

However, I would like to refresh the date in this clock. Is there a way to update the startDateTime variable every 30 seconds? Even running an ajax script to get the date and time from a php script?

Comment: Yes. In your JS use a timer to make an AJAX call, on the server respond with the current date/time. I would suggest returning JSON to make parsing on the client easier.

Comment: I tried setting up a function that made an ajax call every 30 seconds, however the timer then failed to run at all, I'm assuming as the startDateTime var was in a different function?

Comment: I also tried doing the following https://jsfiddle.net/xe0d6j21/1/ however the timer then just shows the minutes and seconds of the local clock rather than using the data from the ajax call.

Comment: First show the code for your update every 30s: I've never know `setTimeout` to fail. Second re. the fiddle: it doesn't seem to call `update` where the AJAX call is made.

Comment: Apologies, missed that part. Have added it here https://jsfiddle.net/xe0d6j21/3/

Comment: First you need to put the code in the question here. Second I'm not going to debug you JS in the fiddle incrementally: go through it line by line in a debugger (all the browsers' dev tools have one): there are clear faults (eg. no element with id `timer`).

Comment: There aren't bugs in the code, I missed out certain sections as what I'm doing has sections that aren't relevant. The initial post is where I am back at and I'm just not sure how to make it retrieve a live datetime on request and store that datetime in the var, and use it. At the moment it's working, but the clock doesn't refresh until you reload the page, as it's stored in the var.